# Is it possible to set timeouts individually for Toastr?

Tags: javascript, toast, toastr

Can you make one toastr last for 30 seconds while the rest stay for the default amount of time? I can't seem to figure out if it's possible. I've tried the following:

`toastr.info('Message here', 'Title', {'timeout': '30000'});`

and

`toastr.info({'message':'Message Here', 'title': 'Title', 'timeout': '30000'});`

and

`toastr.info('Message Here', 'Title', 'timeout'=='30000');`

to no avail.

ETA: There was a spelling error. `timeout` should `timeOut` and there shouldn't be any quotes around timeOut or 30000.

**The Solution**

`toastr.info('Message here', 'Title', {timeOut: 30000});`

Comment: Was your issue resolved once the typo was corrected?

Comment: Yes, the spelling error was the issue..

Answer (score 4):

Try it like this without the ', your passing a JS object which should not be in quotes, unless you need to pass a string as a parameter

```
toastr.info('Message here', 'Title', {timeout: 30000});
```